# MySQL query rows to columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot, where-clause

Does anyone know how to make rows into columns while still beign joined?

```
SELECT p.id
     , f.title 'column'
     , v.value 
  FROM custom_fields f
  JOIN custom_field_values v
    ON v.custom_field_id = f.id
  JOIN projects p
    ON p.id = v.related_to_id
 WHERE p.deleted = 0
```

[image: y]

The rows in column should be the columns and still be grouped by id with value

So it should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    p.id, 
    max(case when cf.title = 'Rental (FSG)' then cfv.value end) rental_fsg,
    max(case when cf.title = 'Model Year'   then cfv.value end) model_year,
    max(case when cf.title = 'Product'      then cfv.value end) product,
    max(case when cf.title = 'Partner'      then cfv.value end) partner,
    max(case when cf.title = 'SAP delivery / invoice number' then cfv.value end) sap_delivery
from custom_fields cf
join custom_field_values cfv on cfv.custom_field_id = cf.id
join projects p on p.id = cfv.related_to_id
where p.deleted = 0
group by p.id
```

Note that I modified your query to use table aliases (`cf`, `cfv`, `p`): they make the query easier to write and read.

Comment: What if i need to join cfv with a different table like join clients c on c.id=p.client_id AND cfv.related_to_type = 'clients'    join projects p on p.id = cfv.related_to_id AND cfv.related_to_type = 'projects'